# Is it possible to run a group containing chains in celery?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to run some chains inside a group and for some reason it is being blocked or and the task doesn't start at all. It just stops and halts.

Basically the code boils down to this:

```
group([
       chained_tasks[0],
       chained_tasks[1]
      ]
      ).apply_async()
```

which hangs forever, I would appreciate any help, I checked backendresult and rabbitmq they are running fine. I can even execute chained_tasks[0].apply_async() and it works properly.

here is how a chain looks like:

```
job_chain = (
                process_task.s(chip_measurement_object.raw_result_ref,
                               process_args,
                               process_args['file_path'],
                               process_args['meas_data'],
                               process_args['marker_data'],
                               process_args['session']
                               ) |

                update_marker_data.s() |

                plot_task.s(chip_measurement_object.id) |

                grade_task.s(chip_measurement_object.id) |

                postgres_async_res_update.s(chip_measurement_object.id, self.input_args)
)
```

the tasks are on purpose mutable because I need to propagate parents' task result.

and here are my settings:

```
# Sensible settings for celery
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False
CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERY_TASK_PUBLISH_RETRY = True
CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS = False

# By default we will not ignore result
# If you want to see results and try out tasks_old interactively, change it to False
# Or change this setting on tasks_old level
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False
CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS = False
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 600
```

Comment: A chain of 1 task doesn't make sense, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes you are right, it doesn't make any sense but I had written it wrong here, thanks for pointing it out, I updated the code here. It is the same result, it just hangs.